# Can I subsitute crushed tomatoes with tomato puree?

Tags: substitutions

I am making tortellini tuscan soup. Recipe calls for can of crushed tomatos I guess I grabbed puree instead. Recipe further calls to mix with 1 box chicken stock....can I use the puree or is my dinner ruined?

Comment: You *guess* you grabbed puree? Could you please clarify what you have and whether you already put it in the pot?

Comment: If you've already added it, you haven't ruined the soup; the flavor profile remains the same. It  may have more of a tomato based soup. You might want to add a bit less stock since the puree is not quite as thick as the crushed tomatoes.

Comment: @Stephie: "I guess" when used with a fact known to the speaker is an idiom used to express sheepish minor embarrassment.  I think this is the intent here.

Comment: @LorelC. I have read the weirdest things in my time at SA / SE, and if I learned one thing, it's "ask, don't assume" . :-)

Comment: puree or concentrate? :)

Comment: Puree is usually a little thicker than crushed. It's also a bit smoother in texture. Just don't cook things quite as long, and your result will be perfectly edible.

Answer (score 2):

You've substituted tomato for tomato (both precooked). It might not be exactly what you were intending to make but it will be fairly similar (very similar in flavour, less so in texture). It will certainly be edible. You might want to adjust the quantities of other liquid ingredients, or cook for a little longer before asking the pasta (if that's an option at this stage) just to thicken it a little.

This is the sort of substitution some people might choose to make to suit their tastes so you don't need to worry about it.